# create custom rewrite rule for php files

Tags: php, url-rewriting, seo

i m a new on SEO, doing first time and totally confused how to this,

```
http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/demo/konkanconnect/realestate/index.php?pages=propertyforsell
to
http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/demo/konkanconnect/realestate/property/sell

and

http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/demo/konkanconnect/realestate/index.php?pages=details&property_id=68
to
http://www.XXXXXXXX.com/demo/konkanconnect/realestate/property/property-name
```

How to do this , give me a clue, thanks in advance.

Comment: Google "mod_rewrite".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a `.htaccess` file and use `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule property/sell index.php?pages=propertyforsell [L]
RewriteRule property/(.*) index.php?pages=details&property_name=$1
```

Notice in the second rule, you cannot translate the `property-name` value in the URL to a `property_id` directly. You'll either have to pass it in as another parameter, or look it up from the name on your server. The following will achieve what you want:

```
RewriteRule property/([0-9]+)/(.*) index.php?pages=details&property_id=$1
```

The file should be placed inside your `demo/konkanconnect/realestate/` directory.

Comment: i have used your code like RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /demo/konkanconnect/realestate/index.php?pages=$1 [L]
in my htaccess file, still it not giving the desired result

Comment: What are you typing in the address bar?

Comment: index.php?pages=propertyforsell

Comment: Working fine now, so after rewriting how to redirect? mns if anyone click the link "index.php?pages=propertyforsell" how to redirect them "property/sell"